# Insert function not working

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am implementing Sqlite db on my project using Phonegap. I know the problem is something to do with  my insert statement because when I point the database success to my query and ultimately my querysuccess function I am getting alerts that the query was successful and the number of rows added is 0. I have tried and tried this is various different ways but to no avail. (If there are obvious errors it is because I am self-learning.)

```
   function insertRecord(dbtx, userName, imagePath){
db = window.openDatabase("database", "1.0", "Profiles", 5000);
userName=document.getElementById('userName').value;
imagePath;
var insertRec="INSERT INTO USERS (username, imagePath) values ("+userName+", "+imagePath+")";
    db.transaction(function(dbtx){dbtx.executeSql(insertRec, [], queryDB, insFail);
    });
    }
function insFail(){
    alert('The insert is still failing');
}
   ....
   function successCB() {
    db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Profiles", 5000);
    db.transaction(insertRecord, errorCB);// IF I PUT THE QUERYDB HERE INSTEAD OF INSERTRECORD IT WORKS BUT OBVIOUSLY THE RETURN IS ALWAYS 0
    console.log('The db and table are working');
```

This is my button to insert

```
   <input id="saveProfile" type="button" value="Save" onClick="insertRecord(dbtx, userName, imagePath);">
```

Comment: Have you trued wrapping your variables in apostrophes when inserting? Like so: `'"+userName+"', '"+imagePath+"'`

Comment: Tom, thank you so much, that worked. Frustratingly simple. I presume I now use an if/else to prevent from adding blank rows over and over?

Comment: You evidently just needed a fresh set of eyes! And check my answer for catching blank rows.

Comment: Yes, I am also learning that walking away for a while can sometimes be the best approach!

Comment: What will happen when `username` is set to `O"Reilly`? This is what placeholders should be used for. Use `tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO USERS (username, imagePath) VALUES (?, ?)", [userName, imagePath])` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using parameterized queries you're avoiding this type of error and a possible [sql injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)

```
var insertRec="INSERT INTO USERS (username, imagePath) values (?, ?)";

db.transaction(function(dbtx){
    dbtx.executeSql(insertRec, [userName, imagePath], queryDB, insFail);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add apostrophes like so:

```
var insertRec="INSERT INTO USERS (username, imagePath) 
               values ('"+userName+"', '"+imagePath+"')";
```

And to prevent multiple blank inserts simple wrap your insert statement in:

```
if(userName != '' && imagePath != ''){
    // Your code
}
```